# Custom Calendar Layout view

Tags: android, view, calendar

I'm trying to make a custom android calendar app in order to add a new missing feature of the existing one. I want to add the ability to let the user change the year as he can change the day and the month, but I get this error now:

```
public CalendarCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CalendarCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    initializeUILayout();
    setUpCalendarAdapter();
    setPreviousButtonClickEvent();
    setNextButtonClickEvent();
    setGridCellClickEvents();
    Log.d(TAG, "I need to call this method");
}

public CalendarCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


private void initializeUILayout(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, this);
    previousButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.previous_month);
    nextButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.next_month);
    currentDate = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.display_current_date);
    addEventButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_calendar_event);
    calendarGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid);
}
private void setPreviousButtonClickEvent(){
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            setUpCalendarAdapter();
        }
    });
}
private void setNextButtonClickEvent(){
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            setUpCalendarAdapter();
        }
    });
}
private void setGridCellClickEvents(){
    calendarGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private void setUpCalendarAdapter(){
    List<Date> dayValueInCells = new ArrayList<Date>();
    mQuery = new DatabaseQuery(context);
    List<EventObjects> mEvents = mQuery.getAllFutureEvents();
    Calendar mCal = (Calendar)cal.clone();
    mCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int firstDayOfTheMonth = mCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    mCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -firstDayOfTheMonth);
    while(dayValueInCells.size() < MAX_CALENDAR_COLUMN){
        dayValueInCells.add(mCal.getTime());
        mCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Number of date " + dayValueInCells.size());
    String sDate = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
    currentDate.setText(sDate);
    mAdapter = new GridAdapter(context, dayValueInCells, cal, mEvents);
    calendarGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

My XML component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_custom_calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previous_month"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_current_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="@string/Current_date"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next_month"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_right"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_calendar_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2018"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/Sun"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/Mon"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/tus"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wed"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/win"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/ther"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fri"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/FrI"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/Sat"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="7" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Finally the error I get:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.meslim.datessc.Activities.CalendarCustomView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.meslim.datessc.Activities.CalendarCustomView
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.meslim.datessc.Activities.CalendarCustomView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.meslim.materialcalendar-n8O1N1I7885zZEqtbhJnmA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.meslim.materialcalendar-n8O1N1I7885zZEqtbhJnmA==/lib/arm64,

Comment: Is proguard enabled in your Manifest? Then add the class to -keep in proguard settings.
Otherwise, check if the path you have written in the xml (in which you have called the component) is correct - "com.example.meslim.datessc.Activities"

Comment: i enabled the proguard  form the gradle . then i checked for the path its correct ..so i had this error 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.example.meslim.materialcalendar.CalendarCustomView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.example.meslim.materialcalendar.CalendarCustomView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at com.example.meslim.materialcalendar.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)

Comment: Disable proguard. It'll be easier to check your code.